# Stencil: <ion-nav> inside <ion-pane-split> don't work properly

Tags: ionic-framework, menu, nav, stenciljs

these are my stencil and ionic version

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ionic/core": "one"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stencil/core": "1.0.0-beta.8"
  }
```

I'm trying to use the `<ion-menu>` inside a `<ion-split-pane>` like in a ionic app, this is my code (this is the original repo of this code https://github.com/modemlooper/stencil-pwa-sidemenu ):

**app-root.tsx**

```
[...]
render() {
    return (
      <ion-app>
        <ion-router useHash={false}>
          <ion-route url="/" component="app-home" />
          <ion-route url="/profile/:name" component="app-profile" />
        </ion-router>

        <ion-split-pane when="lg">
          <ion-menu side="start">
            <ion-header>
              <ion-toolbar color="primary" />
            </ion-header>

            <ion-content forceOverscroll={false}>
              <ion-list>
                <ion-menu-toggle autoHide={false}>
                  <ion-item href="/">
                    <ion-icon slot="start" name="home" />
                    <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>

                <ion-menu-toggle autoHide={false}>
                  <ion-item href="/profile/piero">
                    <ion-icon slot="start" name="person" />
                    <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
              </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
          </ion-menu>
          <ion-nav main />
        </ion-split-pane>
      </ion-app>
    );
  }
[...]
```

The problem is that  `<ion-nav main />` gives me this error:  
And without **"main"** the split pane don't work properly

[image]

This is the expected behaviour

[image]

How is it possible to fix this? I don't get how to use properly the ion menu inside a split pane...
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I have the split-pane working in an app. There are a couple differences with your implementation:

- `ion-nav` is wrapped in an `ion-content` element with an ID attribute
- The `ion-content`s ID is referenced in `ion-split-pane[contentId]` and `ion-menu[contentId]`

```html
<ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
  <ion-menu contentId="main-content">
    ...
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-content id="main-content">
    <ion-nav />
  </ion-content>
</ion-split-pane>
```